# How to calculate the loading time of a website (with all contents) using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to calculate the loading time of a website (given by it's URL) with all contents (pictures.. etc), anyone can help ? using PHP

Comment: Have you done any research and attempts? If not, you need to do that first. If you have, you need to share the code and explain the issue.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Have you tried something before asking? If so, what? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.
About your question, please note that you can compare this time with the Firefox or Chrome Console time.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, I have done some researches but the only thing that I get is the time that it takes to load PHP only

Comment: The network tab of Chrome is pretty good at this

Comment: @apokryfos can I do it using PHP ?

Comment: No. Images are typically served as static assets directly via the webserver and also asynchronously from the HTML so you can't use PHP to time how long those take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can do like that:

```
$start = microtime(true); // Put it from the begining of the page

// Your ccontent

$finish = microtime(true); // Put it in the very end of the page

$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.';
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with javascript, i'm using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timerStart = Date.now();
  </script>
</head>
  <!-- put everything you need in here -->
  <div id="timeloading"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      var time = Date.now()-timerStart;
      $('#timeloading').html('Page loaded after '+ time);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [microtime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function in php can make it better

```
$start = microtime(true); // Put it from the begining of the page

// Your code

$finish = microtime(true); // Put it in the very end of the page

$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.';
```

Comment: This is not a solution for the OP's question. This would only calculate the time it takes for PHP to execute the code on the server, not how long it takes to load the web page (including images etc, which is what the OP asks for).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actionally I want to calculate the loading time of a website given by his URL only, I don't have the code

Comment: Magnus Eriksson yes it's true, I want to calculate the time that it takes to load everything